# Pass the value of a dynamically generated href tags to file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, hyperlink, file-get-contents

I came up to this problem where I have a set of links and I need to get the value of the selected one. I am using AJAX to acquire want I want. But is there another way? My current code is not working on other browsers and IOS devices. Anyway this is how it goes:

For example I have 2 dynamically generated links:

[Link 1](http://google.com) (Value is Google)

[Link 2](http://yahoo.com) (Value is Yahoo)

Say I clicked Link 1. I need to get the value (in my case I used title="Google") of that link which is "Google" and pass that variable to a file_get_contents using variable $linkName. So it will look like:

```
file_get_contents("http://domain.com/link_contents/includes/**$linkName**")
file_get_contents("http://domain.com/link_contents/includes/**Google**")
```

I'm using CodeIgniter framework btw.

As of now, I have a working code and used AJAX. But, it's ONLY working with Chrome browser using: Desktop and Android devices. Sadly, it's not working on IOS devices. As far as I can remember, it was working few days ago with IOS but suddenly it's not. I'm in the process of researching on that too if my AJAX code has an effect to IOS devices.

Anyway. It was actually my first time to do AJAX so I apologize my code is quite messy. But this is how I did it:

On my header.php I have the ff:

> ```
>         $(document).ready(function(){ 
>               var getLink = $('.linkClass');
>               getLink.each(function(i){
>                 $(this).click(function(){   
>                     var linkName = $(this).attr('title');
>                     $.ajax({
>                         url: 'http://domain.com/asset/file_get_contents.php',
>                         type: "POST",
>                         data: { getFromLinkClass: linkName }
>                     }).done(function( result ) {
>                         $('#divID').html(result);
>                     });
>                 });
>             });
>         });
> ```

On my domain.com/asset/file_get_contents.php file,

> ```
>   $linkName = $_POST["getFromLinkClass"];
>        if ($linkName != null) {
>   $links = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/link_contents/includes/$linkName", true); echo $links;
> ```
>
> }

Lastly, on my index.php I can just call the html result which is

```
<div id="divID"></div>
```

As I said, this is working but in Chrome only: on Desktop and Android Chrome.

Any suggestions/ideas/comments? Or is there any other way to do this so that it will work on other browsers and IOS devices?

=======================

UPDATE:

I changed my script, disregarded my AJAX code and used pure Javascript instead. It's now working well with other browsers too.

Comment: None of the URLs above have `http://` or `https://`, which means they are all being treated as relative links. If your real code is lacking the protocol, add it and see whether it fixes your problems.

Comment: Hi @EdCottrell, I forgot to add it on my code blocks above. I edited it. But my real code includes the http://. My code is working though. But not in other browsers and IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$links = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/link_contents/includes/".$linkName, true);
echo $links;
```

Try This.. You must add `http://` or `https://` as protocol if you want to access external urls. Also concat `$linkName` after URL

Comment: Based on OP's edits to the question, this won't fix the problem (see the discussion in comments above).

Comment: Hi @Vicky, thanks for your answer. My bad I forgot to include the http:// on my question above. And like what Ive said in the comments, the code is working but not in other browsers.

Comment: @theladybug Please create a fiddle if you can

Comment: @VickyGonsalves, I tried to create a [PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/29f-6ak) for you. Not sure how to create a fiddle with external files so I just included the set of codes needed. I added some comments on the code too.

Comment: is `http://domain.com` is your domain or 3rd party domain? Because it can give you `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error

Comment: @VickyGonsalves, what I have now is my domain. The error you mentioned, is it still possible to occur even if my code works on Chrome Desktop and Android? My only problem was that it's not working on IOS devices.

Comment: Is it pure web page or are you trying to make a webview based app for iOS and Android?

Comment: It's a pure web page. :)

Comment: It's working on my end too. But not in IOS devices. Did you try it on iPad/iPhone?

Comment: no i tried in safari..check your devices's connectivity if there is an issue with it..

Comment: Alright. I'll try to debug it again. :) Will update you. Thanks for the time, @VickyGonsalves! :)